# How to access more than 4gb from a bootable ChromeOS USB image?

Tags: bootable-media, google-chrome-os

I've created a bootable Neverware Chromium OS image on a 64gb usb stick. I expected to see the full 64gb available from the ChromeOS file explorer, but it only shows 2gb free.

I suspect this has something to do with the FAT formatting necessary(?) for booting, but I would still expect to see the remaining space as a separate mount point.

Comment: Unfortunately you need a bootloader as soon as you add additional partitions so the answer to this is probably no.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this right you have a usb stick with chrome os installer on it. When you put the installer on the drive it only shows 2gb free because of the way an iso (or bin in this case) burns to the disk (more specifically, a usb drive in this case) The FAT file system only supports up to 2gb but your computer is going to use FAT32 if it's more than 2gb in size.